# View not rendering with given size

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-ios

I got a weird issue with react-native using expo, as you can see on the images, some rendered elements don't have the width and height that I've give to them, but instead a random number between (A little more or a little less). It's not a big deal when you have a simple list but when you have to display a nested array (see images), you can have weird and undesired spaces, and you can clearly see with the borders that there is a problem.

(Completely new blank expo project version 3.22.3, code below work as expected with react native web so you can't reproduce using codesandbox for example)

[Simple Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDii4.png)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

export default function App() {
    const array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {array.map(() => (
                <View style={styles.row} key={Math.random()}></View>
            ))}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    row: {
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 30,
        height: 30
    }
})
```

[Nested Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKHg.png)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

export default function App() {
    const array = [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    ]

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {array.map((row) => (
                <View style={styles.row} key={Math.random()}>
                    {row.map(() => (
                        <View style={styles.column} key={Math.random()}></View>
                    ))}
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    row: {
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    column: {
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 33,
        height: 33
    }
})
```

So if you have any idea.. Thanks !

Comment: Can you provdie an Image? because I tested both codes and they look the same size for me.

Comment: The `borderWidth` of a half a dp could make for weird results i think. Try increasing it to 1 or leave it out

Comment: @yesIamFaded I've already posted images just click on the link ! But if you don't see them : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDii4.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKHg.png

Comment: @spitox oh yeah i didnt see it

Comment: @Attaque Already tried, even with no borderWidth I still have weird result

Comment: @spitox what if you add a margin of 1 or a padding do the elements change size? maybe its because they sit right on top of each other

Comment: @yesIamFaded Already tried, it work but some elements still have a random size, and for my project I really need a nice grid without margin .. : 
Bug : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhyJd.png 
Good : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsKbs.png 
I really don't understand what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot shows the styles from **ExpoRoot**. You need to look at the properties **View**.
Everything is showing correctly. The rendered elements have the width and height you specified.

For the second problem, I think this is only on the Android emulator. If you build or test on a real device, you should be fine.

You can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to create a react-native project and test the code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are wright, i've also tried on sandbox and yes it work perfectly fine with react-native-web. I've tried using expo on my real phone + android and ios emulator but the problem persist everywhere.. as you can see here : https://imgur.com/89lMEYn, width and height are 33 but when rendered the size change..

Comment: I gonna try to build the project and test outside expo

Comment: Try to render without borderWidth. 
Maybe something will change?

Comment: I have build an apk file and it's work perfectly on my phone ! So yes the problem come from expo, thanks for you help !